# Vuetify display helper classes not working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, breakpoints

I have the following helper classes applied to a `Navigation` and `BottomNavigation` component.

I want the `BottomNavigation` to show on smartphones only, the `Navigation` should be shown on tablets and everything greater than that. So I applied the following classes:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <div class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <NavigationDrawer v-if="showMenu" />
    </div>

    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>

    <div class="hidden-md-and-up">
      <BottomNavigation v-if="showMenu" />
    </div>
    <Snackbar />
    <Loader v-if="isLoading"></Loader>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

But when I look for example in the Google Chrome console in an iPad view with the `1024 x 767` dimensions, it doesn't show any navigation. It doesn't have something to do with `v-if="showmenu"` because that function only checks on which url the user is (register/login). But if I am looking at those helper classes it should show me the `Navigation` component right?

I tried creating a CodeSandBox to show you that on certain screensizes it doesn't show any navigation while I think it should.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-merkle-4kgoj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the helper classes. They are working fine.

It's `v-navigation-drawer` that is hiding itself in tablet view. Try adding `mobile-break-point="959"` prop.

```html
<v-navigation-drawer app mini-variant mobile-break-point="959">
```

You may have to tweak the value to your needs.